# Overload resolution ambiguity - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, csvtojson

```
var input = File(response)
        try {
            var csv = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
            var csvMapper = CsvMapper();
            var mappingIterator: MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> =  csvMapper.reader().forType(Map.class).with(csv).readValues(input);
            val list: List<Map<String, String>> = mappingIterator.readAll();
            println(list);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Issue is in the `fortype()` function in the line `var mappingIterator: MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> =  csvMapper.reader().forType(Map.class).with(csv).readValues(input)`;

Comment: Please mention What is the exact compiler error you are getting.

Comment: On a related note, have tried using `csvMapper.readValue<MutableList<ClassName>>()`

Comment: The example you've given is not valid Kotlin code. Also, if you're using Jackson it may expect a Java class while you may be passing a Kotlin class. Try `.forType(Map::class.java)`.